# SQLite: consecutive invocation of finalize

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have a function which aims to delete a concrete row from a SQLite database by an UID identifier.

The sequence is the following:
1. Create select query to check if the row exists
2. Prepare the query
3. Bind the row UID
4. Step
5. Finalize
If the row exist
{
    6. Create delete query
    7. Prepare it
    8. Bind the UID
    9. Step
    10. Finalize
    11. Finalize
}

As you can see first it checks if the row exist in order to notify the caller if the required UID is wrong, than it create new delete query.

The program works as expected in ~14/15 test cases. In the cases where the program is crashing it crashes to the last finalize invocation (11th point). I've checked all the data and it seems that everything is valid.

The question is what is the expected behaviour of consecutive invocation of finalize function. I tried to set 5 invocations of finalize one after another but the behaviour is the same.

Comment: I don't think I understand this correctly. Are you trying to finalize the same statement multiple times? You should only finalize it once. According to the documentation ( https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html ), it is "a grievous error" to use a prepared statement after having finalized, and I would assume that also applies to further finalize calls.

Comment: In one particular case i have this two consecutive invocations of finalize. I also checked the documentation but thought that finalize would have any kind of protection. But now it seems to have some kind of undefined behaviour. That's why i created this question.

Comment: Well, it looks like there's protection for calling it on a NULL pointer ("harmless no-op"). I don't think there's such protection for invalid pointers, though, and I think the pointer becomes invalid after finalizing the statement once. The documentation mentions " undefined and undesirable behavior such as segfaults and heap corruption" - perhaps that's why it works only sometimes. You could also try checking the return statement of the second finalize call to see if it returns `SQLITE_OK`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html) doesn't feel the need to state this explicitly, it's fairly obvious that what you're doing is "undefined behaviour" (within the scope of the library).

Much like `delete`ing dynamically allocated memory, you are supposed to finalize *once*. Not twice, not five times, but *once*. After you've finalized a prepared statement, it has been "deleted" and no longer exists. Any further operations on that prepared statement constitutes what the documentation calls "a grivous error" (if we presume that a superfluous call to `finalize` constitutes "use"; and why would we not?).

Fortunately there is **no** reason ever to want to do this. So, quite simply, don't! If your design is such that you've lost control of your code flow and, at the point of `finalize`, for some reason have insufficient information about your program's context to know whether the prepared statement has already been finalized, that's fine: much like we do with pointers, you can set it to `nullptr` so that subsequent calls are no-ops. But if you *need* to do this, you really should also revisit your design.

Why did it appear to work for you? Pure chance, much like with any other undefined behaviours:

> Any use of a prepared statement after it has been finalized can result in undefined and undesirable behavior such as segfaults and heap corruption.

See also: *"Why can't I close my car door twice without opening it?"* and *"Why can't I shave my imaginary beard?"*

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. It is obvious that i will redesign the code in order to remove this consecutive invocation of finalize. The reason of the question was to understand the problem clearly, which was achieved. Thanks again.